# Google custom search on the top level domain is not also showing results from sub-domains

Tags: subdomain, search-results, google-programmable-search-engine

We have a multi-site Drupal install on which we are using Google Custom Search. When we use a search on the base URL we get a much smaller result count than we do when we the same search on a sub-domain.

For example, the search for the string ‘Camping’ returns 8 results when done on the top-domain and on a sub-domain I get over 40 results; two of which are results found on the searched sub-domain.

I’m looking for any settings that will help the top-domain search return all the results including the ones found on the sub-domain. Or an explanation for the shortened count.